# is using past perfect continuous correct in this case?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect, perfect-continuous

Is this sentence correct and can I say the same thing using another tense?

> When I saw her account I realised that she had not been using her account for years.

Comment: for years,not since.

Comment: As edited it's fine.

Comment: The tense is fine, but no native speaker would say this. It should be "When I saw her account I realised that she had not been using it for years."

Comment: Is there another way in which i can say the same thing without using past perfect continuous? And thanks in advance.